# jquery expand/toggle - initial div size

Tags: jquery, css, toggle, slide, expand

Please see my code below...

I am puzzled and want to initially show 30px (in height) of the below div. At present I can only toggle to show or hide.

What I actually want is to show the first 30px and toggle/show anything contained below that.

```
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
  // Hide the "view" div.
  $('div.view').hide();
  // Watch for clicks on the "slide" link.
  $('div.slide').click(function() {
  // When clicked, toggle the "view" div.
  $('div.view').slideToggle(400);
  return false;
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="view">
  <p>shown/hidden depending on the toggle above. </p>
  <p>shown/hidden depending on the toggle above. </p>
  <p>shown/hidden depending on the toggle above. </p>
  <p>shown/hidden depending on the toggle above. </p>
  <p>shown/hidden depending on the toggle above. </p>
  <p>shown/hidden depending on the toggle above. </p>
  <p>shown/hidden depending on the toggle above. </p>
  <p>shown/hidden depending on the toggle above. </p>
  <p>shown/hidden depending on the toggle above. </p>
</div>
<div class="slide" style="cursor: pointer;">Show/Hide</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

Add this css

```
.view{
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 30px;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $divView = $('div.view');
    var innerHeight = $divView.removeClass('view').height();
    $divView.addClass('view');

    $('div.slide').click(function() {
        $('div.view').animate({
          height: (($divView.height() == 30)? innerHeight  : "30px")
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w6eqk/1/)**

Comment: You need to set overflow to hidden or this will not work right.  Also, animating to `100%` won't work right unless the div is in a parent with a set height, in which case it will animate to 100% of the parent.

Comment: @JamesMontagne - Check my edited answer all that is fixed along with demo

Comment: Only comment now is that if the width of the element is not static, after animating to the old height, you could still have clipped text if the window was resized.  May not be an issue though.

Comment: Yes, there is always a way to improvise it based on such conditions

Answer (score 0):

OK, so what I would do is set the content to overflow:hidden, and then just dynamically change the height of the box on the toggle. If overflow is set to hidden, then anything that falls outside the width/height of the box will... well, it will be hidden.

So you would do something like this:

The HTML...

```
<div class="view" style="overflow:hidden;height:30px">
    ... (your normal code) ...
</div>
```

And in the JS...

```
$('div.slide').click(function() {
  var height = $('.view').css('height');

  if (height == 30) 
     $('.view').css('height', 'auto');
  else
     $('.view').css('height', 30);
});
```

Something like that, anyway. Haven't tested that code, but that's the basic idea.

Hope that helps. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

```
.view_height{
height : 30px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="view view_height">
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.slide').click(function() {
     // When clicked, toggle the class.
    $('div.view').toggleClass("view_height");
   });
});
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Vknqw/

Comment: This, unless you're using jQuery UI, will make the div "jump" toggle. The OP wants an animated slide.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I can see it working here http://jsfiddle.net/Vknqw/ what jquery url should I use? http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: very strange... I have copied eveything from here http://jsfiddle.net/Vknqw/ and not expanding...
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.view_height{
  height : 50px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
p{
 width : 400px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('div.slide').click(function(){
    $('div.view').toggleClass("view_height");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="view view_height">
  <p>text </p>
etc...
</div>
<div class="slide" style="cursor: pointer;">Show/Hide</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: very simple you need to put under $(document).ready(funtion(){  .... }); ..fiddle does by default

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you're trying to do, what you really need is to animate your height to `auto`.  However, this isn't possible.  I came up with this to simulate that:

```
$("div").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    if($this.height()==30){

        // set height to auto in order to check how tall it is in current window size    
        $this.css("height","auto");
        var height = $this.height();

        // done checking height, set back to 30
        $this.css("height","30px");

        $this.animate({height: height + "px"},1000, function(){
            // animation done, set height to auto to allow resizing with window resize
            $this.css("height","auto");        
        }); 
    }else{
        $this.animate({height: "30px"},1000);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/txKt7/1/

*NOTE: This is just a proof of concept which is not using your actual html markup.  It would need to be adjusted slightly to fit your exact situation.*

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should suffice:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .view { height: 30px;
            overflow: hidden;
          }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".slide").click(function() {
        if(!$(".view").hasClass('maximized')) {
            $(".view").addClass('maximized');
            $(".view").animate({ height: '+=250' }, 'slow');
        } else {
            $(".view").removeClass('maximized');
            $(".view").animate({height: '30' }, 'slow');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks... the initially loading of the 30px div works, but clicking on the link doesn't expand to show the rest of my content. Any ideas?

Comment: Updated the code, should be good. Check out this fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/3v3L2/)

Answer (score 0):

is this what you mean ?

http://jsfiddle.net/eiu165/ew5dH/

```
// Hide the "view" div.
$('p').hide();
$('p').eq(0).show();
$('span').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('p').next().toggle();
});
```